# How to create war file for jruby on rails application

Tags: java, jrubyonrails, warbler

I have a rails project which is using `jruby-9.1.2.0` with `java version "1.8.0_101".`

Now i want to create a warble file for my project, so i am using this below command

`warble`

But it is giving me following error `ERROR: Can't find header dir for ruby. Exiting...`

Since i am new to jruby, I am not able to figure out this problem.